# In Javascript, how can I refactor some repeated anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript, refactoring

The following code is redundant---the same anonymous function appears three times.

How do I refactor it?

```
$(".operation").resizable({
create: function(event, ui) {
    var width = $(".operation").width()
    $("#width span.text").text(width)
},
resize: function(event, ui) {
    var width = $(".operation").width()
    $("#width span.text").text(width)
},
stop: function(event, ui) {
    var width = $(".operation").width()
    $("#width span.text").text(width)
},
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would declare the function:

```
function setWidth(event, ui) {
    var width = $(".operation").width();
    $("#width span.text").text(width);
}

$(".operation").resizable({
    create: setWidth,
    resize: setWidth,
    stop: setWidth,
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a local variable:

```
     (function() {
       var f = function(event,ui) {
           var width = $(".operation").width()
           $("#width span.text").text(width)
       }
       $(".operation").resizable({
       create: f,
       resize: f,
       stop: f,
       })
    })()
```

the upside is that you do not pollute the global namespace (global object).

You can define a global function if you don't mind.

Comment: +1, but assuming he's already running inside a closure/function, the extra closure isn't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

declare a new function

```
function xxx(event, ui) {
    var width = $(".operation").width();
    $("#width span.text").text(width);
}
```

then set it as the callback:

```
$(".operation").resizable({
    create: xxx,
    resize: xxx,
    stop: xxx
});
```

Comment: You see I am not a fan of that name because of the lack of p0rn related code.

Comment: create, resize and stop are not pr0n-related??